# Can a phone support lte band 41 but not support band 38?

Tags: 4g, google-pixel

The only difference in Google Pixel's versions for North America and for the rest of the world is their support for different lte bands and carrier aggregation.

E.g., in tech specs (https://madeby.google.com/phone/specs/) it is stated that the US version only supports B41 for TDD LTE, while RoW version supports B38/39/40/41

However, I found in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_frequency_bands) that band 38 is actually a subset of band 41.

Does this mean that the US version of Pixel supports b38?
Will LTE work on US version of Pixel if the carrier provides only band 38?